# Is there a way to make an multicolumn treeview at tkinter with multiples checkboxes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to mark some options then depending how many checkboxes I markeddo several thing. I have a multicolumn treeview with heading. Is it the best way? How could I do it? Do I have to think to use another widget or maybe another library? I am using the next example, so i would like to have another tag at column 4 (similar to column 5) and click on column 4 then unchecked column 5 and checked column 4, then same clicking at column 5 regarding column 4.

Thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()


class CbTreeview(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        kw.setdefault('style', 'cb.Treeview')
        kw.setdefault('show', 'headings')  # hide column #0
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        # create checheckbox images
        self._im_checked = tk.PhotoImage('checked',
                                         data=b'GIF89a\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\xf9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x02#\x04\x82\xa9v\xc8\xef\xdc\x83k\x9ap\xe5\xc4\x99S\x96l^\x83qZ\xd7\x8d$\xa8\xae\x99\x15Zl#\xd3\xa9"\x15\x00;',
                                         master=self)
        self._im_unchecked = tk.PhotoImage('unchecked',
                                           data=b'GIF89a\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\xf9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x02\x1e\x04\x82\xa9v\xc1\xdf"|i\xc2j\x19\xce\x06q\xed|\xd2\xe7\x89%yZ^J\x85\x8d\xb2\x00\x05\x00;',
                                           master=self)
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style.configure("cb.Treeview.Heading", font=(None, 13))
        # put image on the right
        style.layout('cb.Treeview.Row',
                     [('Treeitem.row', {'sticky': 'nswe'}),
                      ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': 'e'})])

        # use tags to set the checkbox state
        self.tag_configure('checked', image='checked')
        self.tag_configure('unchecked', image='unchecked')

    def tag_add(self, item, tags):
        new_tags = tuple(self.item(item, 'tags')) + tuple(tags)
        self.item(item, tags=new_tags)

    def tag_remove(self, item, tag):
        tags = list(self.item(item, 'tags'))
        tags.remove(tag)
        self.item(item, tags=tags)

    def insert(self, parent, index, iid=None, **kw):
        item = ttk.Treeview.insert(self, parent, index, iid, **kw)
        self.tag_add(item, (item, 'unchecked'))
        self.tag_bind(item, '<ButtonRelease-1>',
                      lambda event: self._on_click(event, item))

    def _on_click(self, event, item):
        """Handle click on items."""
        if self.identify_row(event.y) == item:
            if self.identify_column(event.x) == '#5': # click in 'UnServed' column
                # toggle checkbox image
                if self.tag_has('checked', item):
                    self.tag_remove(item, 'checked')
                    self.tag_add(item, ('unchecked',))
                else:
                    self.tag_remove(item, 'unchecked')
                    self.tag_add(item, ('checked',))



tree = CbTreeview(root, columns=("Table No.", "Order", "Time", "Served", "Unserved"),
                  height=400, selectmode="extended")

tree.heading('Table No.', text="Table No.", anchor='w')
tree.heading('Order', text="Order", anchor='w')
tree.heading('Time', text="Time", anchor='w')
tree.heading('Served', text="Served", anchor='w')
tree.heading('Unserved', text="Unserved", anchor='w')
tree.column('#1', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=100)
tree.column('#2', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=600)
tree.column('#3', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=100)
tree.column('#4', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=70)
tree.column('#5', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=30)

tree.pack(fill='both')

for i in range(5):
    tree.insert('', 'end', values=(i, i, i))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to parse a CheckboxTreeview from ttkwidgets and get the checkbox status of all the items in the tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976372/trying-to-parse-a-checkboxtreeview-from-ttkwidgets-and-get-the-checkbox-status-o)

Comment: It looks like you already know how to emulate a checkbox in the tree, it's not clear why you can't use the code you already have to create more checkboxes.

Comment: No, thanks. I want to implement with a treeview set up with heading not a list.

Comment: Hello Bryan, yes I want to emulate several checkbox per row in the tree. This is the question, I can not find a right way to do it. I dont have clear if the treeview has any limitation emulating more than one tag per item. Because I would not share the same column.

Comment: Maybe another widget is better for making something like that. I dont have idea.

Comment: Why not just try using multiple tags and see what happens?